# What Remote Desktop Client to install

Tags: remote, client

I use Ubuntu 20.04 with Fluxbox as a window manager.

I need you to recommend an application that acts as a remote desktop client,
that supports the most common network protocols such as VNC, XDMCP, SSH, etc.

I would use it to remotely access my company computer.

In my company, all computers work with Debian Buster.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is that you install and use Remmina.

Remmina is a powerful remote desktop client, available in the repositories, designed for those who need to access their computers remotely.

Among its many benefits are: supports RDP, VNC, NX, XDMCP and SSH. Quick connections by users directly putting in the server address, viewport fullscreen mode. Enables users to maintain a list of connection profiles. Offers tabbed interface, optionally managed by groups.

To install it with its compatible plugins, open a terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install remmina remmina-plugin-*
```

Once installed, run it and configure a new connection to your remote server, pressing [Ctrl + N] or going to Connection - & gt; New and configure the remote connection profile with the required parameters:

```
Name:
Group:
Protocol:

Server:
User name:
Password:
Domain:
Resolution:
Color depth:
Share folder:
```

Once you have configured all the necessary settings, save the settings by clicking the Save button and from the main interface, you can see all your configured remote connection profiles.

To connect using VNC, select the connection profile, edit the settings, select VNC from the Protocols drop-down menu. Configure basic, advanced, and ssh settings for the connection and click Connect, then enter the user's SSH password.

After the connection to the remote machine is established using the VNC protocol, enter the user's login password from the desktop login interface.

Source: https://www.remmina.org/wp/